# Get status of scheduler job from python

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-scheduler

I have a scheduled job running on Cloud Scheduler, and I would like to get its status ("Success", "Failed") from python. There is a python client for cloud scheduler [here](https://googleapis.dev/python/cloudscheduler/latest/index.html) but can't find documentation on how to get the status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the status with the library like that

```
    from google.cloud.scheduler import CloudSchedulerClient
    client = CloudSchedulerClient()
    print(client.list_jobs(parent="projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/LOCATION"))
```

*I chose list_job but you can also use get job.*

In the JSON object that you receive, you have a [status field](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/reference/rest/Shared.Types/Status). If empty (meaning no error), the latest call was in success. If not, it was in error and you have the GRPC error code in the field.

Comment: is there a way to convert the output which is of type [ListJobsPager](https://googleapis.dev/python/cloudscheduler/latest/scheduler_v1/cloud_scheduler.html#google.cloud.scheduler_v1.services.cloud_scheduler.pagers.ListJobsPager) to a dict ?

Comment: No out of the box. The pager type allow you to iterate over the result and when the page is over to request for the next one. It's a special structure. Perform a loop and create your dict, then use it as you wish.

Comment: I am trying to find a way to have access to `status` from the output of `client.list_jobs(parent="projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/LOCATION")`...

Comment: Ok, so one can iterate over the output of `client.list_jobs(...)`, get the job's name with the attribute `.name` of the elements of this output, and get the job's status with the attribute `.status` that can be converted to a string with `str()`